# Topological equivalence and continuity on topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Could someone help me with this proof, please?
I am aware that topologically equivalent means that the set of open sets are the same for both metrics.

Let $f : (X,d) \to (Y,m)$ be a continuous function between metric spaces. If defined
$$d^*(x,y) := d(x,y) + m(f(x),f(y)),$$
show that $d$, $d^*$ are topologically equivalent and, furthermore, $d^*$ makes $f$ a uniformly continuous function.

Consequently, on topological spaces, the notion of continuity is the same as uniform continuity. (I am so confused with this statement because I should prove that delta only deppends on epsilon)

Until now, I have this:

1. Let $U$ be an open set in $(X, d^*)$.

Since $d^*(x, y) = d(x, y) + m(f(x), f(y))$, for any $x \in U$, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that the open ball $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ with respect to the metric $d^*$ is contained in $U$.

Consider the open ball $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ in $(X, d^*)$. For any $y \in B_{\epsilon}(x)$, we have $d^*(x, y) < \epsilon$, which implies $d(x, y) + m(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$.

Since $m(f(x), f(y)) \geq 0$, it follows that $d(x, y) < \epsilon$. Thus, $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ is an open ball in $(X, d)$, and hence $U$ is open in $(X, d)$.

2. Let $V$ be an open set in $(X, d)$.
   Since $d^*(x, y) = d(x, y) + m(f(x), f(y))$, for any $x \in V$, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that the open ball $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ with respect to the metric $d$ is contained in $V$.

Consider the open ball $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ in $(X, d)$. For any $y \in B_{\epsilon}(x)$, we have $d(x, y) < \epsilon$, which implies $d^*(x, y) < \epsilon + m(f(x), f(y))$.

Since $m(f(x), f(y)) \geq 0$, it follows that $\epsilon + m(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon + \epsilon = 2\epsilon$. Thus, $B_{2\epsilon}(x)$ is an open ball in $(X, d^*)$, and hence $V$ is open in $(X, d^*)$.

For the second part I am trying to prove that $m(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$, but I have no clue.

Comment: +1 This is much better than the [previous version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4887024/continuity-and-topologically-equivalent-metrics) of your question, but in the future, please don't delete and re-ask questions, even if they're closed. When you edit your question, it triggers an automatic review, and the community can vote re-open your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sort of messing up what you need to prove. For the first part, for example, you only proved $B_\epsilon(x)$ is contained in an open ball in $(X, d)$, not that it is such an open ball. (Most likely it is not.) The following is a fixed version of the proof:

For clarity, I'll use $B_\epsilon(x)$ to denote the $\epsilon$-ball around $x$ in $(X, d)$ and use $B^\ast_\epsilon(x)$ to denote the $\epsilon$-ball around $x$ in $(X, d^\ast)$.

For the first part, let $U$ be an open set in $(X, d^\ast)$, we need to show $U$ is also open in $(X, d)$. That is, for any $x \in X$, we need to show that there is some $\epsilon > 0$ s.t. $B_\epsilon(x) \subset U$. Fix $x \in U$. Since $U$ is open in $(X, d^\ast)$, there is some $\delta > 0$ s.t. $B^\ast_\delta(x) \subset U$. As $f$ is continuous, there exists $\epsilon' > 0$ s.t., whenever $d(x, y) < \epsilon'$, we have $m(f(x), f(y)) < \delta/2$. Let $\epsilon = \min\{\delta/2, \epsilon'\}$. Then I claim that $B_\epsilon(x) \subset U$, as required. Indeed, if $d(x, y) < \epsilon$, then in particular, $d(x, y) < \delta/2$ and furthermore $d(x, y) < \epsilon'$. By our choice of $\epsilon'$, we have $m(f(x), f(y)) < \delta/2$. Hence, $d^\ast(x, y) = d(x, y) + m(f(x), f(y)) < \delta/2 + \delta/2 = \delta$, that is, $y \in B^\ast_\delta(x) \subset U$. Thus, $B_\epsilon(x) \subset U$, as claimed.

For the second part, let $U$ be an open set in $(X, d)$, we need to show $U$ is also open in $(X, d^\ast)$. That is, for any $x \in X$, we need to show that there is some $\epsilon > 0$ s.t. $B^\ast_\epsilon(x) \subset U$. Fix $x \in U$. Since $U$ is open in $(X, d)$, there is some $\epsilon > 0$ s.t. $B_\epsilon(x) \subset U$. Now, if $d^\ast(x, y) < \epsilon$, then as $m(f(x), f(y)) \geq 0$, we have $d(x, y) \leq d(x, y) + m(f(x), f(y)) = d^\ast(x, y) < \epsilon$, that is, $y \in B_\epsilon(x) \subset U$. Thus, $B^\ast_\epsilon(x) \subset U$, as required.

This shows that open sets under the two metrics are the same, so they are topologically equivalent.

Now, under $d^\ast$, we show that $f$ is uniformly continuous. Indeed, for any $\delta > 0$, we simply choose $\epsilon = \delta$. Then whenever $d^\ast(x, y) < \epsilon$, we have $m(f(x), f(y)) \leq d(x, y) + m(f(x), f(y)) = d^\ast(x, y) < \epsilon = \delta$. This shows $f$ is uniformly continuous.

The comment "on topological spaces, the notion of continuity is the same as uniform continuity." is perhaps better understood as saying that there isn't a good notion of uniform continuity when you just have a topological space. Indeed, the above argument shows that, if $(X, d)$ is a metric space and $f$ is continuous, then there is always a topologically equivalent metric that makes $f$ uniformly continuous. Or, to put it another way, it is impossible to distinguish between uniformly continuous functions and other continuous functions, by just looking at topology. To define uniform continuity, more information than just what sets are open are needed. (The general framework under which uniform continuity can be defined is called uniform spaces. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space)

Comment: Thank you for you answer, just one question, y∈B∗δ(x)⊂U
 that "y" is just another element of X, but how do I know that in fact, it exists?

Comment: @zulamedina Are you referring to the third paragraph (“for the first part”)? In that case, no, $y$ is not just an arbitrary element of $X$. If you trace through the arguments in that paragraph, what I proved is that whenever $d(x, y) < \epsilon$, then $y \in U$. That is to say, I’m proving $B_\epsilon(x) \subset U$, since $B_\epsilon(x)$ consists exactly of those $y$ with $d(x, y) < \epsilon$.